# typescript array of required items

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to force all elements in array?

Only requirement is "type connection" to main Book type.

I hope there is some way to make tuple type ['id', 'title'] from Book type generically, as suggested in comments. Or at least array length check...

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=110#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gWAFBSgSwBMAuKAZ2ACd8A7Acxz2H2ABsJSLr7GoA3fGXwAjdqWEJ2AQxq8pAV2AALOJU5VaDbAF8cOUJFgJEAMXwRWhMqiiIIIOADMjSPdgPR4SMxasBRAA8qKQBjYAAeQOCwiEIfS2sIIIgaKxdTcwSAPhsoylCIrwzfMgAaKDyC2PirLLcQuBoKKClKNXSaskqw8IByIl6oAB8oXuY2CF6sgG0AXRtp-sJe%20YB6VagVAHcoYDgoR1UQ6Ag21QJncfYoGjhgAhoQ1iJYh5a2qRAAfiA).

```
type Book = {
  id: string
  title: string
  visible: boolean
  author: string
}

type BookFields = keyof Book

type BookFieldsExtract<ExtractedFields extends BookFields> = Extract<BookFields, ExtractedFields>

const arr: BookFieldsExtract<'id' | 'title'>[] = ['id'] // how to force error if title not inclided in array?
```

Use case:

```
type SelectedBookFields = BookFieldsExtract<'id' | 'title'> 
type ApiRes = ApiResBook<SelectedBookFields> // {book: {id: string, title: string}}

 const bookFields: SelectedBookFields[] = ['id', 'title'] // i just don't want to forget some fields when making request

  const response = await fetchAPI<ApiReqBookBody, ApiRes>(
    'book',
    { fields: { book: bookFields } }
  ) // response type is {error: true} | {book: {id: string, title: string}}
```

Comment: What do you need this for? Can you provide a list of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Do you have finite number of elements? If so you are looking for tuple `['id', 'title'] | ['title', 'id']`

Comment: This array if for api request fields that user will want to get. Array of strings only (keyof Book).

Comment: @MaciejSikora how can i make this tuple type from Book?

Comment: Can I ask why you need tuple/array and not record?

Comment: @MaciejSikora added use case

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it will work for you, but I would create some value constructor for this tuple with some overloads in order to guide the dev. Consider:

```
function makeArrFromKeys<T, A extends keyof T>(obj: T, key1: A): [A]
function makeArrFromKeys<T, A extends keyof T, B extends keyof Omit<T, A>>(obj: T, key1: A, key2: B): [A, B]
function makeArrFromKeys<T, A extends keyof T, B extends keyof Omit<T, A>, C extends keyof Omit<T, A | B>>(obj: T, key1: A, key2: B, key3: C): [A,B,C]
function makeArrFromKeys<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): K[] {
    return keys;
}

const book: Book = {
    id: 'i',
    title: 't',
    visible: true,
    author: 'a'
}
const arr = makeArrFromKeys(book, 'id', 'author', 'title')
// arr has type ['id', 'author', 'title']
```

Our function is extends to three keys, but if you will follow overloads you can go further. Function will make the tuple exactly how you wanted - keys are unique and if you provide you need 'id', 'title' you will get `['id', 'title']`.

I would name it compromise between a crazy type which probably we can do, and just maintainable and safety code.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, found a way that works for my use case:

```
const bookFields: ['id', 'title'] = ['id', 'title']
type BookFields = typeof bookFields[number] // 'id' | 'title'
```

Comment: I thought you want tuple from Union and not other way around

Comment: @MaciejSikora i just wanted type connection, if it was possible to make tuple from union, it's will be good, but this will work for me too, just with additional step.